# How to replace number with text for each row in dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
 id status
241 1
451 3
748 3
469 2
102 3
100 1
203 2
```

Now what I want to do is this:

1 corresponds to 'good' , 2 corresponds to 'moderate', 3 corresponds to 'bad'.

So my output should be like this:

```
 id status
241 good
451 bad
748 bad
469 moderate
102 bad
100 good
203 moderate
```

How to do this ? I tried to do this using if else but it is getting complicated.

Comment: `level <- c("good", "moderate", "bad"); df$status <- level[df$status]` should work.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a labelled factor.  You can try:

```
df$status <- factor(df$status, labels=c('Good','Moderate','Bad'))

> df
   id   status
1 241     Good
2 451      Bad
3 748      Bad
4 469 Moderate
5 102      Bad
6 100     Good
7 203 Moderate
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is the type of status column. If they are not factors, you can do(as pointed out by Pascal)

```
level<-c("Good","Moderate","Bad")
df$status<-level[df$status]
```

data

```
df<-data.frame(item=c("apple","banana","orange","papaya","mango"),grade=c(1,3,2,1,3),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And if it is set as factors, you may(as pointed out by Jay)

```
df$status<-factor(df$status, labels=c('Good','Moderate','Bad'))
```

data

```
df<-data.frame(item=c("apple","banana","orange","papaya","mango"),grade=c(1,3,2,1,3),stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
```